# Send an HttpRequest without response in Progress OpenEdge

Tags: openedge

I am using IHttpRequest to send a request to a service that has to create a message. 
At this moment the Progress procedure holds until it receives a request from the service, while it should just continue. (Fire and forget principle)

This is the class I use to make the call to the service:

```
USING Progress.Lang.*.

USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.ClientBuilder.
USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.IHttpRequest.
USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.IHttpResponse.
USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.RequestBuilder.
USING Progress.Json.ObjectModel.JsonObject.

BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.

CLASS TOOLS.externals.zato.SendDesadv: 

    DEFINE VARIABLE baseURL     AS CHARACTER     NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE servicePath AS CHARACTER     NO-UNDO INITIAL send/json".
    DEFINE VARIABLE serviceURL  AS CHARACTER     NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE oRequest    AS IHttpRequest  NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE oResponse   AS IHttpResponse NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE input_json  AS JsonObject    NO-UNDO.

    CONSTRUCTOR PUBLIC SendDesadv ( INPUT wave_nr AS INTEGER ):            
        input_json = NEW JsonObject().
        input_json:Add("wave_nr", wave_nr).
        invokeZato(input_json).        
    END CONSTRUCTOR.

    METHOD PUBLIC VOID invokeService( INPUT input_json AS JsonObject ):
        setServiceUrl().

        SESSION:DEBUG-ALERT = TRUE.
        oRequest = RequestBuilder:Put(serviceURL, input_json)
           :AcceptJson()
           :REQUEST.
        oResponse = ClientBuilder:Build():Client:Execute(oRequest).
    END METHOD.

    METHOD PUBLIC VOID setBaseUrl(  ):
        IF LENGTH(PDBNAME(2)) = 3
            THEN baseURL = "http://foo".
        ELSE baseURL = "http://bar".

    END METHOD.

    METHOD PUBLIC VOID setServiceUrl(  ):       
        setBaseUrl().
        serviceUrl = baseUrl + servicePath.
    END METHOD. 
END CLASS.
```

I have already tried to just leave `oResponse = ClientBuilder:Build():Client:Execute(oRequest).` out of it, but then nothing is sent.

How could I use the "fire and forget" principle here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible to do asynchronous communication with IHttpRequest. A huge disadvantage!

A possible workaround might be to use a OS utility like curl or wget for the call instead. There are ways of making os calls asynchronous. They will however spawn new procedures (and not just new threads).

In windows you can do like this basic example:

```
OS-COMMAND VALUE("dir") NO-WAIT.
```

In Unix/Linux you can do

```
OS-COMMAND VALUE("ls &").
```

This will however introduce new problems: how to input/output data to wget/curl, how to handle "stay" procedures, possibly higher system load etc.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite late -- but I add this for the benefit of future searchers.

If you have an AppServer, you can do an asynchronous run there.  (And can even get a response back when the process finishes, if you like.)

If timing is not critical, there are other possibilities -- like adding the request to a queue and have a separate process to monitor that queue.  I am toying with the idea of setting up an IPC mechanism to tell the background monitor that it should look NOW, thus minimizing the lag time between queue and dequeue.